# want to update the column of specific row of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have added a buttonfield named "accept" in the gridview..I want to update the column 'status' of bitfield to '1' of that specific row when admin clicks on accept.. Im working on c#

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"   AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" Width="1000px"

                  AllowPaging="True" PageSize="8" 
CssClass="Grid" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  AllowSorting="True">
```

```
    <Columns>
         <asp:ButtonField Text="Accept" CommandName="Update" runat="server"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fname" HeaderText="fname" SortExpression="fname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="emailid" HeaderText="emailid" SortExpression="emailid" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="contact" HeaderText="contact" SortExpression="contact" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="type" HeaderText="type" SortExpression="type" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="username" SortExpression="username" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="password" HeaderText="password" SortExpression="password" />
    </Columns>
<PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"></PagerStyle>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbrubyConnectionString3 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT  seller.fname, seller.emailid, seller.contact,seller.type, login.username, login.password FROM seller INNER JOIN login ON seller.sid=login.lid where login.status= ORDER BY login.createdate ">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event handler for GridView1_RowCommand, looking for the command "Update", and grab the DataItem so you know which item to update, then update it in the database, and then rebind your gridview.

You could also make an ajax call to update the value, which would be faster (less data to transmit and receive), and wouldn't require a full page refresh, but that is more work to set up.

Add an identifier (CommandArgument) to your command by changing:

```
<asp:ButtonField Text="Accept" CommandName="Update" runat="server"/>
```

to:

```
<asp:ButtonField Text="Accept" CommandName="Update" runat="server"
  CommandArgument="<%# Eval("emailid") %>"/>
```

Add event handler by changing:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server"
  Width="1000px" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="8" CssClass="Grid"
  AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  AllowSorting="True">
```

to:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server"
  Width="1000px" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="8" CssClass="Grid"
  AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  AllowSorting="True"
  OnRowCommand="GridView1_OnRowCommand">
```

Then write your update in the backend by adding:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  switch(e.CommandName)
  {
    case "Accept":
      var email = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
      Accept(email); // write this function
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Would it be okay if you can show how to do it? I'm new to it. Thanks in advance

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much :D